# Jquery Validation Mobile number Already Exist

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Jquery Code for validating the form on submit:

```
 $("#frmAddEditCustomer").validate({
            rules: {
                //"companyname": "required",
                "txtcustomerid": "required",
                "mobile1": {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true,
                    minlength: 8,
                    remote: {
                        url: "AdminWeb.asmx/HelloWorld",
                        type: "post",
                        data: {
                            mobile1: function () { return $("#mobile1").val(); }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "remark": "required",
                "firstname": "required",
                "email": {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                },
                "lastname": "required",

            },
            messages: {
                "txtcustomerid": "CustomerID is required",
                //"companyname": "Company Name is required",
                "mobile1": {
                    required: "Mobile Number is required",
                    digits: "Please enter only digits.",
                    minlength: "Please enter at least 8 digits.",
                    remote: "Mobile number already in use!"
                },
                "email": {
                    required: "Email Address is required",
                    email: "Enter proper Email Address"
                },
                "remark": "Short Note is required",
                "firstname": "First Name is required",
                "lastname": "Last Name is required",
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                if ($("#hidEditID").val() > 0) {
                    EditCustomer();
                }
                else {
                    AddCustomer();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

URL Call Method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public bool HelloWorld()
{
    return false;
}
```

I want to validate the mobile1 number if already exist in database then it should display error message of remote default i am passing to false to get the error but its not working.
Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Check you network tab in browser console, and make sure whether request goes to server..

Comment: i checked with debugger the call is going to the server

Comment: Do you get proper response.. I mean is the status is 200 and response comes as false from server in the console?

Comment: In console i am not getting any response

Comment: What about request status in network tab?

Comment: its appearing with status 200

Comment: Not sure what particularly is your problem.. **[Check this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998990/problem-with-jquery-validate-plugin-remote-validation)** and **[this too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474043/asp-net-webforms-jquery-validates-remote-method)**.. You might get some ideas..

Comment: `mobile1: function () { return $("#mobile1").val(); }` why so verbose? `mobile1: $("#mobile1").val()` is equivalent